# Only having the circle radio, loop the circumference coordinates (x, y)

Tags: java, math, minecraft

I'm making my own Minecraft world border plugin for myself use.

I have a spawnpoint, that can be any coordinates, and I check the distance between player and the spawnpoint. If the distance exceeds 1000 (that is the radio) I cancel the user movement.

So I can say my circle radio is 1000.

The problem is: I want to draw in the world the circle borders, so the player can see the world borders. I need to iterate over the coordinates of the circumference, and I dont have any idea of how to do that (my maths are really poor)

Thanks you

Comment: Did you check the algorithm at [Wikipedia: Circle drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_drawing_algorithm)?

Answer (score 1):

Usually to iterate through the coordinates of a circe you want to use a bit of trigonometry.
You create a variable angle which starts from 0 and you iterate it by the step you need until 2π, then your x coordinate will bee cos(angle) and your y coordinate will be sin(angle).

Then probably you will have to round a bit those value considering you want to use them in a minecraft word where you can't place blocks in decimal coordinates

Comment: Is simply a cartesian map like every videogame so how can I translate it to code? having only radius and the spawn reference point (x, y)

I need to fill all the blocks (x,y) of circumference

        int radio = 1000;
        for(int g = 0; g < 360; g++) {
            double x = radio * Math.cos(g);
            double y = radio * Math.sin(g);
            System.out.println("X:" + x + ", Y: " + y);
        }

I have this already but is not enough

Comment: g shouldn't range from o to 360 but from 0 to 2π as i said because fro sin an cos the angle is not in degrees but in radiants, you just have to increment this value by a small enough step to have all the coordinates you need then you round them to minecraft coordinates

Comment: I don't know how to translate that to code... as you say the step is a integer number, the world is a simply cartesian map like any other game